# Can't remove pvpn-ipv6leak-protection connection after ProtonVPN complete removing

Tags: networking

I have removed protonvpn package on ubuntu 22.04 using apt and cleared cache and config folders. Then, I deleted pvpn-ipv6leak-protection using nmcli d but after reboot it shows again. How to remove it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The connection file was found and deleted using command:

> rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/pvpn-ipv6leak-protection.nmconnection